# How to position WPF controls within a Canvas on a Fullscreen window?

Tags: wpf, canvas, resize, fullscreen

I am currently working on a full screen WPF app. The app goes fullscreen at the Window_Loaded event.

Inside the window, I have a Canvas. Inside the Canvas, I have a MediaElement and 3 Images. Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_CS4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_CS4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded" AllowDrop="True" Background="Black">
    <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" >
        <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1" MediaEnded="mediaElement_OnMediaEnded" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="390" VerticalAlignment="Center" MouseLeftButtonDown="mediaElement1_MouseLeftButtonDown_1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="767" Canvas.Left="-384" Canvas.Top="-190"/>
        <Image x:Name="image1" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Height="390"  Width="791" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="-795" Canvas.Top="-392" />
        <Image x:Name="checkImg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Margin="50,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67"/>
        <Image x:Name="crossImg" Height="54" Margin="0,196,663,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonDown="crossImg_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="67"/>
    </Canvas>

</Window>
```

**Problem**

When I run the application, the canvas is not be able to update and fit the whole full screen. So when I try to set positions to the Images (with Canvas.SetLeft(this.crossImg,0); for example), it looks like the canvas is actually moved when the window goes fullscreen.

I need to set the "x y coordinates" of the images and change them accordingly. I have tried with a grid but it does not let me overlay an Image on top of the MediaElement, so I get that the canvas is the way to go.

**Question**

How can I resize the canvas to fit the window programatically when the window goes to fullscreen mode?

Comment: Set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`. Note that you don't need the Loaded event for fullscreen display. Just set `WindowState="Maximized"`. And you can of course put child elements on top of each other in a Grid.

Comment: @Clemens thank you actually setting WindowState="Maximized" is a lot more efficient as it is doing it from the start instead of maximizing when loading! I also set the WindowStyle="None" so that it is truly fullscreen

Comment: `Grid` *does* let you put multiple elements on top of each other and it sounds like that (or some other panel) would probably be a better option. I'd like to know what problem you had using `Grid` and would like to see some illustration of what you want to the finished program to look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Tag THis will give you options like fill stretch and etc